# How to convert Image<Gray, Byte> to Image<Gray, float>?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to substract 1 image from another, somewhat like this:

```
Image<Gray, float> result, secondImage;
Image<Gray, byte> firstImage;
result = firstImage - secondImage;
```

But it gives an error

```
Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray,byte>' and 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray,float>'
```

Maybe i need to convert firstImage into `Image<Gray, float>` type. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote from [the documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Color_and_Depth_Conversion):

> **Color and Depth Conversion**
>
> Converting an Image between different colors and depths are simple. For example, if you have  Image img1  and you wants to convert it to a grayscale image of Single, all you need to do is
>
> ```
> Image<Gray, Single> img2 = img1.Convert<Gray, Single>();
> ```

So, in your case, you could use

```
result = firstImage.Convert<Gray, float>() - secondImage;
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never seen or used emgucv before and got this answer simply by googling and reading. (Yes, this is a bit of a "you can do this, too!" nudge.)

Comment: @Heinzi  ... and now this is Google's first search result for the question!